# Open file picker dialog with Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am working with Angular, ionic and capacitor js and I am trying to open the file picker dialog in IOS like this one :
[The open file dialog preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H6xs.jpg)

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Capacitor File Picker plugin for iOS and Android.

You can find the plugin [here](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-file-picker).

They provide an example of using the `FilePicker.pickFiles()` method to select files:

```
const pickFiles = async () => {
  const result = await FilePicker.pickFiles({
    types: ['image/png'],
    multiple: true,
  });
};
```

It's important to update the `types` value to your appropriate media type that you are looking for. As the documentation for the plugin suggests, it uses the [IANA Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) standard to specify what media types you can include.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this librairy but the dialog takes all the screen space and it have a small freeze when openning...

Comment: @Galileoomega The speed is likely a performance issue with your device/emulator. You also did not specify the screen space requirement in your question. *This is the correct answer to your question.* If you're not satisfied with the results of the plugin, you can always write your Capacitor plugin and custom interface to display files fetched from your own plugin. Hope this helps and best of luck on your projects!

Comment: @Galileoomega The file picker plugin behaves the same as the image your provided. Please note the image you provided takes up the entire screen space via a fully-expanded sheet modal.